# UITableViewCell swipe to delete doesn't work when cell contains full frame button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swipe

I've put UIButton on UITableViewCell and it takes full frame of cell. 
When I'm trying to swipe cell to start editing mode, button catches this swipe event as usual touch and doesn't forward it to UITableView.

Is there an easy and neat way to forward horizontal swipe on button to UITableView or UITableViewCell, not sure, who should handle this event to start editing mode.

BTW, vertical swipe is forwarded correctly to UITableView and allows to scroll it.

Comment: on which event buttons triggers ?

Comment: Why do you have a button over your entire cell? Why not just use `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: I've tested even in a simple UITableViewController, when button doesn't have an event.

Comment: @rebello95 One button for simplicity. In real life there three buttons that take whole space